# How many circles of radius R with a D distance between them, fit in rectangle of B x L

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, rectangles, packing-problem

i have a rectangle of B x L meters and i want to know how many circles with R radius can fit if there is a space of D between them. All the values wil be integers always.

I tried this.

With this example:

[Initial grid with 10x9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKUtv.png)

i have:
B = 10
L = 9

If radius of circles are R=1 and distance is 3 D=3. I can fit 4 circles (In the image they are the yellow zones)

[Grid with circles put in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlAxx.png)

So, for creating like a formula, i extended the radius of the circles to radius plus D between them, so the radius of the circles will be R + D/2. After that i calculate the area of a circle with that Radius

[Grid with circles and extended radius with distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgzFe.png)

With that area, i divided the area of the rectangle (10 x 9) between the area of the circle and cut the decimals, but the result is 2, not 4  :(

[Results of calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xelNW.png)

I dont know how to get to a valid formula. I'm not a mathematician,  i would appreciate any help. Thanks  :)

Comment: Hi, here you have a really useful website. On the sources you can find the formulas https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/circles-within-rectangle-d_1905.html

Comment: Thanks @HornyPigeon54 , that web seems really cool, i'm studying the algorithm!

Comment: What is the spacing between the circle and side of rectangle? If the circle can touch the sides, then the problem is equivalent to placing circles of radius $R + \frac{D}{2}$ into rectangle of dimension $(B+D) \times (L + D)$. For the case $(R,D,B,L) = (1,3,10,9)$, you can place $5$ instead of $4$ circles into the rectangle (at $4$ corners and $1$ at center). In general, circle packing is a hard problem and there is no known formula for the optimal numbers. A good site for this sort of stuff is [Erich's packing center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html)

Comment: Hi, @achillehui, there is no space between the circles and the sides of rectangle, so the circles can be placed in the corners. Sadly as you say there is no direct formula, but i saw an algorithm in javascript in the page that HornyPingeon54 cited to place circles in rectangles and i rewrote it in Python in my answer. I'm gonna check the site you said :)

Answer (score 1):

after reviewing the [link](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/circles-within-rectangle-d_1905.html) that @hornypigeon54 provided me in the comment of the post, i saw the code that the page used to calculate the number of circles in the rectangle. After modyfing it a little, i came with this function in python to do that calculation. B and L are the dimensions of the rectangle, radius is the radius of the circles and the distance between them. So far the algorithm is working but i'm testing it.

```
def n_circles_in_rectangle(B: int, L: int, radius: int, distance:int) -> int:

    diameter = radius*2
    n_circles = 0

    if ((diameter + distance) <= B and (diameter + distance) <= L):
        posX = (diameter / 2)
        posY = (diameter / 2)

        while (posY + radius <= L):
            while (posX + radius<= B):
                n_circles += 1
                posX = posX + (diameter + distance)

            posX = (diameter / 2)
            posY = posY + diameter + distance

    return n_circles


print(n_circles_in_rectangle(B=10, L=9, radius=1, distance=4))
```